# Parse through multiple nodes using xslt

Tags: xslt

Below is my input xml

```
        <Record>
          <Header>
              <field1/>
          </Header>
          <Body>
              <firstname>x1</firstname>
              <lastname>y1</lastname>
              <company>Test1</company>
          <Body>
          <Body>
              <firstname>x2</firstname>
              <lastname>y2</lastname>
              <company></company>
          <Body>
          <Body>
              <firstname>x3</firstname>
              <lastname>y3</lastname>
              <company>Test2</company>
          <Body>
        </Record>
```

1. I am trying to loop through body and check if the company value is blank,to output the corresponding first name and last name.This whole output,I am mapping to DATA on the target using xslt mapper.Can someone help me with the below code which is not working

   ```
       <?xml version='1.0' ?>
       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="Namespace">
           <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
               <xsl:variable name="NAME" select="/RecordSet/Body"/>
               <xsl:variable name="break">&lt;br&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="tableB">&lt;table Border="1" BorderColor="#000000"  cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" &gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="tableE">&lt;/table&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="trB">&lt;tr&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="trE">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="tdB">&lt;td&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="tdE">&lt;/td&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="nbsp">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:variable name="thB">&lt;tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC"&gt;</xsl:variable>
           <xsl:template match="/">
       <DATA>
               <xsl:value-of select="$tableB"/>
           <xsl:value-of select="$thB"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$tdB"/>&lt;B&gt;FirstName&lt;/B&gt;

                       <xsl:value-of select="$nbsp"/>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$tdE"/>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$tdB"/>&lt;B&gt;LASTNAME &lt;/B&gt;

                       <xsl:value-of select="$nbsp"/>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$tdE"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$trE"/>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$trB"/>
                       <xsl:for-each select="$NAME/Body[string-length(company) &gt; 0]">
       <xsl:value-of select="$tdB"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$MT_NAME/firstname"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$nbsp"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$tdE"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$tdB"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$MT_NAME/lastname"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$nbsp"/>
                           <xsl:value-of select="$tdE"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
               <xsl:value-of select="$trE"/>
           </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$tableE"/>
       </DATA>
   ```
2. The output should be

---

### |FIRSTNAME|LASTNAME|

### | X2      | Y2     |

Comment: Please, edit the question and add this very important and presently missing information: the exact result you want the transformation to produce.

Comment: Hi Dimitre,can you please let me know where to correct the code to loop through the body and check the company field ?

Comment: There should be an "edit" verb in the menu bar following the question -- you need to ckick on it.

Answer (score 3):

The provided code doesn't produce HTML at all -- it produces *strings* -- one-dimensional text.

Also, AFAIK, `DATA` isn't an HTML element.

Also, the provided "XML" is severely malformed.

**Here is an example how to produce an HTML table with XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <td>First Name</td>
       <td>Last Name</td>
       <td>Company</td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Body">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Body/*">
  <td>&#xA0;</td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Body/*[normalize-space()]">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided severely malformed text -- corrected):

```
<Record>
    <Header>
        <field1/>
        <Body>
            <firstname>x1</firstname>
            <lastname>y1</lastname>
            <company>Test1</company>
        </Body>
        <Body>
            <firstname>x2</firstname>
            <lastname>y2</lastname>
            <company></company>
        </Body>
        <Body>
            <firstname>x3</firstname>
            <lastname>y3</lastname>
            <company>Test2</company>
        </Body>
    </Header>
</Record>
```

**A meaningful and sensible HTML table is produced:**

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>First Name</td>
         <td>Last Name</td>
         <td>Company</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>x1</td>
      <td>y1</td>
      <td>Test1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>x2</td>
      <td>y2</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>x3</td>
      <td>y3</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to take a guess at your requirements as they are not very well explained.

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
  <DATA>
    <table Border="1" BorderColor="#000000"  cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
      <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC">
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Body" /> 
    </table>
  </DATA>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname" /></td>
    <td>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="company!=''" >
          <xsl:value-of select="company" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(firstname,' ',lastname)" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </td>
  </tr>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... when applied on this document...

```
<Record>
    <Header>
        <field1/>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <firstname>x1</firstname>
        <lastname>y1</lastname>
        <company>Test1</company>
    </Body>
    <Body>
        <firstname>x2</firstname>
        <lastname>y2</lastname>
        <company/>
    </Body>
    <Body>
        <firstname>x3</firstname>
        <lastname>y3</lastname>
        <company>Test2</company>
    </Body>
</Record>
```

...will yield...

```
<DATA>
  <table Border="1" BorderColor="#000000" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC">
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Company</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x1</td>
      <td>y1</td>
      <td>Test1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x2</td>
      <td>y2</td>
      <td>x2 y2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x3</td>
      <td>y3</td>
      <td>Test2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</DATA>
```

### Note

Notice that the middle record has a cell value of 'x2 y2' for Company as per stated requirements when the input Company is empty or missing.

---

## Update

The input document is still badly malformed. In consideration of the OP's updated requirements, this XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:template match="/">
  <DATA>
    <table Border="1" BorderColor="#000000"  cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
      <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC">
        <th>First name</th>
        <th>Last name</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Body[company='']" /> 
    </table>
  </DATA>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="firstname" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="lastname" /></td>
  </tr>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to the same input document as before, yields...

```
<DATA>
  <table Border="1" BorderColor="#000000" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
    <tr BGCOLOR="#CCCCCC">
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>x2</td>
      <td>y2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</DATA>
```

Comment: Thanks Sean.The requirement is Body is o..unbounded and I only need to output firstname and last name when company is blank and so I am trying to loop though the Body and check if company field is blank or not and if it is blank print the corresponding first and last name.

Comment: I still do not understand. Could you please correct your badly maformed sample input, and provide the matching expected output?

Comment: Your trial spread-sheet doesn't add any thing to the question because it is so full of errors. To really explain an XSLT problem you need to supply use cases (sample input documents and matching expected outputs), a full narrative for the rules of transformation, as well as what version of XSLT, and if 1.0, whether it is server-side or client-side.

Comment: Also, please indicate whether my solution is what your want or not? If not, how is it wrong? My reading of your question and subsequent comments is that it is correct, but I would appreciate an unambiguous response on that.

Comment: Edited the question and provided the sample output.Please check

Comment: I dont want all the 3 nodes to be in the output. I want to loop thorugh Body and print only the first name and last name fields if company is blank.